# Why does Microsoft Visual Studio add a (1) suffix to my solution names?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I'm working an SSIS project, and every time I reload / rename the solution it automagically adds a (1) suffix to the end of the name.   Currently working in SSIS 2012, but I've observed this behavior way back in the Visual Basic 6.0 days.

The 'Read Only' checkbox is not checked, and the file has never participated in source code control.

Anyone know why this behavior occurs?

Thanks.
Jim

** edit to support first comment **

Before I loaded the project, CPMS_Salesforce(1) did not exist.  After trying to add the package to an empty project, it created the (1) file. [image]

Answer (score 0):

When you add a file to a visual studio project, it copies the file to the project folder. If a file of the same name already exists, it increments the name by appending a number to it. 
The file that was already there, but not part of the project, will still sit there unchanged.

Comment: Nope.  I cleaned out the folder of un-neded files, then went into Visual Studio-SSIS and added the project, and it made a copy of the file with a (1) suffix in both the VS project, and in Windows Explorer.  See added image in original question.

Comment: To be clear, we are talking about adding the package, "CPMS_Salesforce.dtsx," to the project CPMS_Salesforce.dtproj, which gets you both CPMS_Salesforce (1).dtsx in the solution explorer and windows explorer.  Do I have that all right?  If so, could you delete CPMS_Salesforce.dtsx and CPMS_Salesforce (1).dtsx both from the project and windows and then try adding it again?